# How to repeat a cronExpression in a specific period of time?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

greetings all
I have a cronExpression that I want it to be started on application startup and repeated every second, I am defining cronExpression via xml configuration as follows:

```
<bean id="myCronTrigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob" /> 
        <property name="cronExpression" >
        <value>${first.trigger.time}</value> 
        </property>      
</bean>
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a SimpleTrigger which is more suited for your usage.

From the [SimpleTrigger lesson](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson05):

> SimpleTrigger should meet your scheduling needs if you need to have a
>   job execute exactly once at a specific moment in time, or at a
>   specific moment in time followed by repeats at a specific interval.

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetailBean" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="1000" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
0/1 * * * ? *
```

(maybe `* * * * ?` * works too)

@see: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html

This fires every second.

If you need an fixed delay of 1 second instead of firering every second, then you could use the Spring 3.0 annotations to: `@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)`

@see: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

BTW: you could use the `@Scheduled(cron="*/1 * * * * MON-FRI")` annotation, instead of XML configuration.

Comment: I want it to fire at 1 pm then repeats every 4 hours

Comment: @sword101: Your wrote: to be started on application startup and repeated every second!!  - use 0 0 1/4 * * ? for 1, 5, 9 o'clock. And have a look at the quarz tutorial (see my answer) it explain it very well!

Comment: my comment was another question sorry